# What are these spheres at bottom-right in 3d viewport?

Tags: interface

[image]

I downloaded a *.blend file and open it.
I saw two strange spheres at bottom-right in 3d viewport.
What's this and how can I turn it on/off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spheres are called *[HDRI Preview](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html?highlight=hdri%20preview)* spheres, in older Blender versions known as *Look Dev HDRI spheres*. You can turn them on/off in the overlay menu. It is used to check the lighting setup of an HDRI.

Comment: thank you. good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps (This can be done only in the Shading Workspace):

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

Here is a shortcut if you don't do the steps mentioned above:

[image]
[image]

Comment: HDR Previews are exclusive to the viewport's Material Preview shading mode, not to a workspace. Workspaces are just UI layout presets, there's nothing exclusive to any of them. The shading workspace just happens to have a viewport with its Shading mode set to Material Preview.